# Django CSV file -database upload error

Tags: django

I have a CSV file and I am trying to populate them to a sqlite database. I have no error message and it works perfectly fine but loads only the last line of the file.

```
MD= MD()
    database = options.get('database')
            filename = options.get('filename')
            dataReader = csv.reader(open(filename))
            for row in dataReader:
                if row[0] != 'ID':
                   bb= 1 if row[3] == 'YES' else 0
                   pro = 'YES' if row[4] == 'Pro' else 'NO'
                   MD.id = row[0]
                   MD.mol = row[1]
                   MD.phase = row[2]
                   MD.warning = black_box
                   MD.pro = pro
                   MD.status = Type.objects.get(description=row[5])
                   MD.name = row[6]
                   MD.stem = row[7]
                   MD.year = row[8]
                   MD.iname = row[9]
                   MD.iyear = row[10]

                   print row[1], row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6], row[0]
                   MD.save()
```

But the print statement prints all the lines in the CSV file. I have no idea what happens. Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the CSV file you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only creating one `MD` instance *outside* of the `for` loop, then saving to that same instance on each iteration of the loop. You need to create a new `MD()` instance for every iteration (per line of the file) if you want to create and save a new record for each line. This is why you are only saving the last line - you are over-writing the pre-existing instance you created. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving always the same object. Try with this:

Put the `MD= MD()` inside the `for`:

```
... # The same here
for row in dataReader:
    if row[0] != 'ID':
        MD= MD()
        ... # The same here
        MD.id = row[0]
        MD.mol = row[1]
        ...
        MD.save()
```